# Why function is not running before rest of the code in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's probably because of my half-knowledge on this but I don't know how to fix it:

Basically I have the following:

1. A button "Check numbers"

```
<Button fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                onClick={this.checkOptOut}
                margin="normal"
                component="label"
              >
```

2. Upon clicking, the function `checkOptOut` is called

```
checkOptOut = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.getOptOutList()
    this.checkNumbers()
  }
```

So basically what I expect is that `getOptOutList` gets called first. It looks like this

```
getOptOutList = () => {
    fetch(`${global.config.url}get-optout-list`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': this.state.auth_header
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(`Checked optout list: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)

        if(data.data.optOutNumbers.length > 0){
          this.setState({}, () => {
            this.setState({
              optOutNumbers: data.data.optOutNumbers
            })   
          })
          return;
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      });
  }
```

And then `this.checkNumbers()` has in the beginning:

```
checkNumbers(){
    //event.preventDefault();


    //this.getOptOutList()
    
    console.log(`Opt out list length: ${this.state.optOutNumbers.length}`)

...
OTHER STUFF
```

I notice that ALWAYS checkNumbers seems to be called/finished first so in the logs I always get
`Opt out list length : 0`

And after that I get the logs of the previous function.

How can I ensure I first run `getOptOutList`, save the state, and then run `checkNumbers`?

Comment: `getOptOutList` does get called first. To make sure, return the fetch and put `this.checkNumbers` inside a then following `getOptOutList`?

Comment: `fetch` is an async function. So you basically call it and it does something behind the curtain. Meanwhile the next function will be executed. `fetch` takes longer than running `checkNumbers`. Return your `fetch` promise and `await` it

Comment: Thanks both, I will test this now and report back!

Answer (score 1):

The `fetch` function is an asynchronous call. Therefore it is executed in the background and will return immediately.

You can use the `Promise` returning from it to wait for it's completeness:

```
getOptOutList = () => {
    // fetch is async and should be returned
   return fetch(`${global.config.url}get-optout-list`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': this.state.auth_header
      }
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(`Checked optout list: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`)

        if(data.data.optOutNumbers.length > 0){
          this.setState({}, () => {
            this.setState({
              optOutNumbers: data.data.optOutNumbers
            })   
          })
          return;
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      });
  }
```

```
checkOptOut = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.getOptOutList()
        .then(() => this.checkNumbers())

  }
```